# How to create a VSTO Outlook Add-In that runs automatically when Outlook is opened?

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to create an Outlook VSTO add-in that will work as follows:

1. There is a configuration screen where user configures syncing
   details
2. Once the syncing details are configured, whenever Outlook is opened or when an appointment is added/updated/deleted to the Calendar, triggers the add-in that syncs with an online server.

Is it possible to create VSTO add-in that runs without user interaction ?

I found this link [VSTO Addin Outlook Appointment delete and write event fired only if opened first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46015455/vsto-addin-outlook-appointment-delete-and-write-event-fired-only-if-opened-first)
but it seems to trigger only when an appointment is opened.

Comment: Of course, you can do anything you want as soon as your addin is loaded.

Comment: Do you mean in the ThisAddin_Startup event ? Or is there any other event that I am missing ?

Comment: Yes, you will have a pointer to the Outlook.Application object by then.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, is there any way that I can keep an add-in running after outlook has closed or push outlook to the background ? I need to sync some data to the server and in case user closes Outlook before the process is done, I need some way to keep the process running.

Comment: No, you cannot do that. And if you prevent Outlook from closing, it will disable your addin. You need to save your sync state so that you can pick where you left the next time your run.